# Deploy Angular in Github Pages

Tags: angular, deployment

I followed the docs in https://angular.io/guide/deployment and use:
`ng build --prod --output-path docs --base-href /<project_name>/` to build Angular project but I can not find "gh-pages branch" option in setting/source.

Comment: You're not supposed to use that option; as the Angular docs tell you, you want to serve from the docs directory (hence the use of that directory in the build command). Pick **master branch /docs folder** in the GitHub repo settings page.

Comment: it's just show "Readme file" in my github pages ^^. what can i do to access to my route?

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot with so little information. If you've actually followed the instructions then I can see no reason it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try again ^^

Answer (score -1):

```
Setup:

1.You have an angular project.

2.Install angular-cli-ghpages package from npm like this
'npm install -g angular-cli-ghpages'

3. You can setup npm script like this or run directly in terminal:
"build-and-deploy-gh-pages": "ng build --prod --base-href ./ && npx ngh --dir dist/[reponame]"

Where ./ can be replaced with:
'https://[username].github.io/[reponame]/'

As a matter of fact, in above link you’ll find your github-page.
You’ll be asked for your github username and password to deploy to gihub pages.

This script will create gh-pages branch automatically and setup your repo for publishing online.

 Next step would be to to run this script as:  'npm run build-and-deploy-gh-pages
```

I've wrote an article in Medium about deploying angular on github pages.

Please have a look [here](https://medium.com/@miki995/angular-7-deploy-to-github-pages-images-assets-7704f3b2005c)

Comment: Let me know if it works, then please mark answer as correct :D

Comment: Sorry I'm late. Thanks you very much.